# how to store textbox multiliple line in same as database in mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, multiline

I create Project In MVC.

I made functionality in my project for giving review to user, but i getting one problem.
so i need help.

[Before Adding review - we are showing multiple line(using enter) in text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLdL0.png)

[After Adding review - it'll display in single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBWGQ.png)

How to Solve this Problem.

JavaScript Code:

```
 $("#saveReview").click(function () {
        debugger
        if($("#saveReviewText").val() == "")
        {
            $("#BookReviewError").text("Review cannot be Empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            var saveStarReview = $("#saveStarReview").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveReview", "Book")',
                data: { "reviewText": $("#saveReviewText").val(), "Bookid" : @Model.Book_Id ,"Rateid" : $("#RateId").val() , "StarReview" : saveStarReview },
                cache: false,
            });
            location.reload();
        }
    });

    $("#addReview").click(function () {
        debugger
        if($("#addReviewText").val() == "")
        {
            $("#BookReviewError").text("Review cannot be Empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("AddReview", "Book")',
                data: { "reviewText": $("#addReviewText").val(),"Bookid" : @Model.Book_Id , "StarReview" : $("#addStarReview").val() },
                cache: false,
            });
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

Added Review Code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="addReviewText"></textarea>
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.BookError))
                        { <span class="text-danger validator"> @ViewBag.BookError </span>}
                        <span class="text-danger validator" id="BookReviewError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs button" value="Add Review" id="addReview" />
                </div>
```

Model Code:

```
 public ActionResult AddReview(string reviewText, int Bookid, byte StarReview)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reviewText))
        {
            _ratingServices.AddUserRating(reviewText, Bookid, StarReview);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["BookError"] = Resource.Messages.EmptyReviewText;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Services Code:

```
 public void AddUserRating(string addReviewText, int Bookid , byte StarReview)
    {
        Rating rating = new Rating();
        rating.User_Id = ProjectSession.UserID;
        rating.Book_Id = Bookid;
        rating.Review = addReviewText;
        rating.Rating1 = StarReview;
        rating.Rating_Time = DateTime.Now;
        rating.Is_Deleted = false;
        _unitOfWork.RatingRepository.Insert(rating);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

storing

Comment: You might save `\r\n` replace `<br>` before save to DB.

Comment: but how can i identify '\n' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass value in controller store database like this

```
public ActionResult AddReview(string reviewText, int Bookid, byte StarReview)
{ reviewText = reviewText.Replace("\n", "<br />");.... so on
```

Create function using javascript when you display your review using view in MVC

```
function multiliner(target, replacer) {
var text = $(target).html();
text = text.split("&lt;br /&gt;");
text = text.join(replacer);
$(target).html(text);
}

$(".multiline.paragraph,.user-rating-list .paragraph").each(function () {
     multiliner(this, "<br/>");
});
```

Give class to your paragraph tag `<p>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of CKEditor for getting or setting your review text.
CKEditor renders data as HTML and you can save it as it is.
Rendering the value will set the value in same format.
Sample Code :

1. Set CKEditor :

   ```
   CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
   ```
2. While passing data to controller get the text of review as :

   var messageBody = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getHtml();

The message body will be formatted in the same manner as the user entered the text.

Try and let me know if you face any issue.